# How to run Websocket application on Elastik beanstalk Java Apache tomcat8 with ws protocol?

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, websocket

Web socket application is running perfectly on local apache tomcat server, but unable to run on Elastik beanstalk , Getting error 404, Method not found